# Connection refused on userinfo request for OpenID Connect

Tags: wso2-identity-server

I'm trying to run the playground sample for OpenID Connect on WSO2IS 5.0 
according to this documentation 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/IS500/OpenID+Connect+with+the+WSO2+Identity+Server+and+WSO2+OAuth2+Playground
but have problems at the point to get userinfo with

```
https://localhost:9443/oauth2/userinfo?schema=openid
```

It redirect to

```
http://localhost:8080/playground/oauth2.jsp?reset=true&error=Connection%20refused:%20connect
```

Same problem happens when I use "implicit" for Authorization Grant Type and try to access the resource URL my_photos.

Any ideas why it doesn't work?

Comment: I just try out this with localhost (both server and tomcat).  it works fine. Please verify again

Comment: It's working on localhost but the error occures if I use the localhost for tomcat and remote wso2is server. The wso2is has no error in log file.

Answer (score 2):

When the WSO2 IS is not reachable from the playground application as `https://localhost:9443/`, you need to change its url in the configuration file:

```
$TOMCAT_HOME/webapps/playground/WEB-INF/web.xml
```

You need to change the param-value for param-name **serverUrl** to the URL of the WSO2 IS.

E.g. my WSO2 IS instance is available at `https://wso2is:9443/` so I needed to change it like this:

```
    <init-param>
         <description>serverUrl</description>
         <param-name>serverUrl</param-name>
         <param-value>https://wso2is:9443/services/</param-value>
    </init-param>
```